# How can I get the background-image value of a div and apply it to the src value of an img tag onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, onclick

I am trying to take the background image of my div (thumbnail) and apply the same value to the main image so that the image changes onclick

I thought this would work.  I have small divs with the class ProductGalleryThumb and one large image with an id MainImage

```
$('.ProductGalleryThumb').click(function () {
    var i = $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('rel') + ')');
    $("#MainImage").html('<img src="' + i + '" />');
})
```

Any help much appreciated as always.

Comment: An **ID** can only belong to **one** element. If this is not the case, use **classes**.

Comment: Thank you, I did know that but overlooked it while getting caught up in this, I have changed the code accordingly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **HTML** should look something like this:

```
<div class="ProductGalleryThumb" style="background-image:url(img1.jpg)"></div>
<div class="ProductGalleryThumb" style="background-image:url(img2.jpg)"></div>
<div class="ProductGalleryThumb" style="background-image:url(img3.jpg)"></div>

<img id="MainImage" src="" alt="" />
```

and here is the **jQuery**:

```
$('.ProductGalleryThumb').click(function () {
    var image = $(this).css('background-image');
    // remove "url(" and ")" to get the url
    image = image.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
    $("#MainImage").attr('src',image);
});
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Makes complete sense and is so obvious when you see it like that, many thanks for your help.  Solved my problem instantly :)

Comment: @KarlHumphries No problem, and yes, I guess it is pretty self-explanatory if you know jQuery basics :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using window.getComputedStyle...

```
$('.ProductGalleryThumb').click(function () {

    // get computed style
    var style = this.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(this, false);

    // img src is inside 'url(' + ')' - slice those off
    var src = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);

    $("#MainImage").html('<img src="' + src + '" />');
});
```

Comment: That is a pretty sweet alternative I must say.